# #1067 - Invalid default value for 'timestamp'

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress, migration, plesk

I transferred a WordPress website from a shared hosting plan using Plesk to a VPS server with a newer Plesk version. When trying to upload the MYSQL database I am getting the following error:

Error
SQL query: Copy

```
CREATE TABLE `XZu2B8_wc_reserved_stock` (
  `order_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `product_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `stock_quantity` double NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `timestamp` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp(),
  `expires` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp(),
  PRIMARY KEY (`order_id`,`product_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

MySQL said: Documentation

> #1067 - Invalid default value for 'timestamp'

Does anyone have any idea how to fix that?

Comment: in mysql 8 it runs without problems , which version do you have

Comment: I'm using "Server version: 5.5.65-MariaDB - MariaDB Server" and "phpMyAdmin: 5.0.2". But for some reason, in my VPS server, I cannot find the option to update the MySQL Version.

Answer (score 3):

This was introduced only in mysql 5.6

For mysql 5.5 you need following  trigger and you need to remove the DEFAULTs
FIRST create the table:

```
CREATE TABLE `XZu2B8_wc_reserved_stock` (
  `order_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `product_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `stock_quantity` double NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `timestamp` datetime NOT NULL,
  `expires` datetime NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`order_id`,`product_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

Then create the trigger

```
DELIMITER $$

 CREATE TRIGGER before_insert_XZu2B8_wc_reserved_stock
 BEFORE INSERT ON XZu2B8_wc_reserved_stock
 FOR EACH ROW
 BEGIN
    IF NEW.`timestamp` IS NULL THEN
       SET NEW.`timestamp`= NOW();
    END IF;
    IF NEW.`expires` IS NULL THEN
       SET NEW.`expires`= NOW();
    END IF;
 END$$
 DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply! I'm sorry for asking, but I am a newbie and I don't really understand where to place the code you just send me. Should I replace it with my own or?

Comment: copy the code in a phpmyadmin SQL tab see https://www.siteground.com/tutorials/phpmyadmin/query/

Comment: MySQL said:

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '...
BEFORE INSERT ON XZu2B8_wc_reserved_stock
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

Comment: i let the name open for your choosing, now i added one, so that you don't have a problem anympore

Comment: Thank you very much for all your help! I really do appreciate it! I'm getting this error: #1146 - Table 'j115449mad_wordpress_c.XZu2B8_wc_reserved_stock' doesn't exist

Comment: a trigger is bound to a table, you have to cvreate your table first, but don't forget to remove the DEFAULT for both DATETIME

Comment: New error: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'CREATE TRIGGER ...
BEFORE INSERT ON XZu2B8_wc_reserved_stock
FOR EACH ROW
BEG' at line 10

Comment: please check my answer again i expanded it a lot